# Is this the right way to frame an opening under my staircase?

Tags: framing, storage

I want to take some studs out to use the space under the staircase of my split level home.

If I were to chop the studs off, add jack studs and make a 2x4 header would that be the right way to do this?

A bad drawing for reference:

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that would be the right way. This wall isn't bearing load<sup>*</sup>, so as long as your header has the robustness to support the studs above and drywall it's adequate.

Since you have a landing post blocking part of the gap you might reduce your new opening to that point.

---

<sup>*</sup> Single top plate, parallel with common joist, near foundation but not supporting a beam....

Comment: For my future reference, are interior walls that don't have a double top plate almost always non load bearing? My home was built in 2015.

Comment: That's generally true. Note, though, that _all_ walls above the basement typically have doubled top plates. This is so that they're all the same height using pre-cut studs.